# Is it optimal way to filter records from table using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have the SQL **Products** table migrated from MongoDb and I use `ASP Core` + `MediatR`. The filtering data comes from frontend `Autocompletes` where user can select multiple values (3 different `ProductGroups` + 2 different `Suppliers` for example). Wanted to ask is my implementation optimal, or did I miss something?
Below the code for action:

```
    [HttpPut("[action]")]
    public async Task<IQueryable<ArticleDto>> Put([FromBody] ProductsQueryAll query)
    {
        var response = await _mediator.Send(query);
        return response;
    }
```

And below the code for MediatR model and Handler:

```
 public class ProductsQueryAll : IRequest<IQueryable<ArticleDto>>
    {
        public string[] ProductGroups { get; set; }
        public int[] SupplierIds { get; set; }
        public string[] Categories { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductsQueryAllHandler : IRequestHandler<ProductsQueryAll, IQueryable<ArticleDto>>
    {
        private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public ProductsQueryAllHandler(DbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _mapper = mapper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));
        }

        public Task<IQueryable<ArticleDto>> Handle(ProductsQueryAll request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ArticleDm>();
            if (request.ProductGroups?.Length > 0)
            {
                predicate = predicate.And(x => request.ProductGroups.Any(y => y == x.ProductGroup));
            }
            if (request.SupplierIds?.Length > 0)
            {
                predicate = predicate.And(x => request.SupplierIds.Any(y => y == x.SupplierId));
            }
            if (request.Categories?.Length > 0)
            {
                predicate = predicate.And(x => request.Categories.Any( y => y == x.Category));
            }


            var entityList = _dbContext.Articles
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(predicate);

            return Task.FromResult(_mapper.ProjectTo<ArticleDto>(entityList));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What SQL does it generate? Look at that for possible inefficiencies. And can't this be done by simply using IQueryable, i.e. no need for PredicateBuilder? Also, "ProductsQueryAll" is IMHO a bad name. It looks like a bunch of words jammed together, plus it isn't true: you're not getting "all" since the request contains arrays you use as a filter, and you're getting articles not products. Why not "GetFilteredArticles(Request/Handler)"?

Comment: do you have similar filtering requirement on other controllers ? or is it just going to be used on this action only ?

Comment: @iSR5 this kind of filtering only on this action

Comment: @user2771704 then I don't think you need to complicate things, a simple service method with the proper arguments, would be enough, and working with simple `IQueryable`  would be enough as well. use `PredicateBuilder` if you have complex query.

Comment: I see, iSR5 and BCdotWEB thanks for you comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Small syntax improvements**

`Foo?.Length > 0` can always be refactored to `Foo?.Any()`

`x => request.SupplierIds.Any(y => y == x.SupplierId)` can be somewhat improved by using
`x => request.SupplierIds.Contains(x.SupplierId)`

I don't particularly like the name `ProductsQueryAll`. `ProductsQuery` seems more appropriate. "All" implies that you're going to get all of them, which is not the case since you're allowing filters.
That being said, there may be circumstances that I'm not aware of that help explain why your name could make sense, e.g. to disambiguate it from something very similar.

I'm aware that this is not something everyone agrees on, but I find the `_` prefix for private fields superfluous, and simply use camelcasing (`context`, `mapper`). That being said, you might be subjected to an existing coding style, at which point I do agree that conformity to the rest of the existing codebase and development team style is more important.

**Query logic**

Because of the nature of your filtering logic, you could've omitted the predicate builder and instead chained your `Where` calls directly. I tend to structure this kind of logic like so:

```
var query = _dbContext.Articles.AsQueryable();

if (request.ProductGroups?.Any())
    query = query.Where(x => request.ProductGroups.Contains(x.ProductGroup));

if (request.SupplierIds?.Any())
    query = query.Where(x => request.SupplierIds.Contains(x.SupplierId));

if (request.Categories?.Any())
    query = query.Where(x => request.Categories.Contains(x.Category));
```

**Returning an `IQueryable`**

This is something you should avoid at all costs. Do **not** return `IQueryable`. Your return type should be `IEnumerable`.

Also note that it is easy to still return an `IQueryable` even when your return type is `IEnumerable` (since `IQueryable : IEnumerable`), but you should actively avoid this. This is done by **enumerating** your `IQueryable`, most commonly done via `ToList` or `ToListAsync`.

Building this off of my previous suggestion:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ArticleDto>> Handle(ProductsQueryAll request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // see previous snippet

    return await query
                   .ProjectTo<ArticleDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                   .ToListAsync();
}
```

Small things to point out:

- Since you're working asynchronously, you should make this method actually asynchronous so you can benefit the most from it.
- `ProjectTo` has two signatures. You used `mapper.ProjectTo(query)` (oversimplified), but I prefer `query.ProjectTo(mapper)` (oversimplified) because it's more consistent with the rest of the syntax being used here, because it's always of the form `query.Method(...)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. A little bit confused about avoiding **IQueryable**. Because in many articles I saw something like `So if you working with only in-memory data collection IEnumerable is a good choice but if you want to query data collection which is connected with database `IQueryable is a better choice as it reduces network traffic and uses the power of SQL language.`

Also often can see statements that **IQueryable** is more performant (please see https://www.webdevelopment.co.nz/post/10x-performance-gain-ienumerable-vs-iqueryable)

Comment: So I thought if I load data from big table I thought that for performance better send query to database with **IQueryable** than use  in memory filtering with **IEnumerable**. Or I get this concept wrong?

Comment: @user2771704: You are correct about the benefits of not loading all data and filtering/sorting/projecting it in-memory; but the handling of an `IQueryable` should be done only on your persistence layer (DAL), and it should cease to be an `IQueryable` when it leaves that layer. I surmise that the party who sent the Mediatr request is not part of your DAL, and therefore it should not receive an `IQueryable` as the result of the request.

Comment: @user2771704: The problem with an `IQueryable` is that it is an implementation leak. You can only properly handle an `IQueryable` when you have concrete knowledge of what data store you're using. The DAL exists specifically to encapsulate the data store knowledge; so that the rest of the application doesn't depend on the specific data storage method. Therefore, only the DAL should be handling a "raw" `IQueryable`, and by the time the DAl returns its data to a not-DAL consumer, it should've enumerated the `IQueryable` so that the consumer doesn't have to interact with the `IQueryable`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I used `IQueryable` because of Using some additional filtering from `Odata` with `[EnableQuery]` attribute in the controller. I will think how to handle this scenario better if possible (probably handle binding manually from ODataRoute).

Comment: @user2771704: Overall, you should try to supply all necessary filter/sorting/projection logic to the DAL, so that the DAL can optimally make use of the `IQueryable` by making sure it only bothers loading the things you actually need. Presumably, you'll need to thread your controller data through your application until it reaches the DAL (i.e. via this Mediatr request)